# Recovering original filename after renaming in Ext4

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4, mv, undelete

If I rename a file with mv command like:

```
mv original_file_name new_file_name
```

Is this possible to recover the original filename on Linux Ext4 file system and if so how that can be done?

Comment: No, it's gone unless you took steps to preserve it through snapshotting or filesystem backups.

Comment: @AndrewDomaszek Sounds good, do you want to post that as an asnwer?

Comment: Hard links are technically different names to the same file. So theres also a tiny chance you have the original file kept in a hard link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the filesystem level, this operation can not be undone: you changed the name assigned to a specific inode, without preserving its previous name.

That said, a *very* small chance exists to retrieve the original name by reading backward the filesystem journal. However, as the journal is a circular buffer (ie: it is continuously overwritten), you need to immediately remount the filesystem readonly and use specialized tools to analyze the journal.

It is way simpler and effective to search the previous name in system logs and the likes: for your example, an extremely simple `history` command would reveal the `mv` command in its entirely, showing both old and new filename.

Comment: Much better answer than mine. The short version is the directory file where the filenames are stored is not backed up.